# Combining different sized arrays into one object?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Python 3.7, Numpy: I have a number of different sized arrays, for example a (5,3), a (3,3) and a (3,2) array. (Background: They define matrices which will be multiplied to an initial vector successively.) To get flexible code (for example to insert a fourth matrix between one of those very easily) I want to store all of them inside one object.

I tried simply putting it into a previously generated zero array which should be big enough to fit all of them, but that has not worked as expected. Code below.

```
for i in range(CollectionSize-1):
        ArrayCollection[:, :, i] = Array(Lenght1[i], Lenght2[i])
```

If I run this lines of code, I get the error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,3) into shape (5,5)
```

What I preferably want to have is an object made of these arrays with none of the dead spots (so if I call `ArrayCollection[:, :, 0]` I want a different sized Array then when I call `ArrayCollection[:, :, 1]`), but I can work with these dead spots being filled with zeros.

I suspect the answer to be pretty simple, please don't be too harsh on me if that is the case, but I slogged with that for too long now.

Also if there is another way of doing what I need rather than storing everything in one object, I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to store all the matrices into a single list/array? If yes I can help with

Comment: Anything wrong with a simple list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? (If you want to store your matrices into a list):

```
a = np.zeros((5, 3))
b = np.zeros((3, 3))
c = np.zeros((3, 2))
m_objects = []
m_objects.append(a.tolist())
m_objects.append(b.tolist())
m_objects.append(c.tolist())
#print matrices
for i in m_objects:
    print(np.matrix(i))
    print("-----")
```

Output:

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
-----
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
-----
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
-----
```

Comment: Ah yes, exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear that you want exactly the same. Enjoy.

Comment: @webDev I'm not sure that he wants/needs the arrays to be converted to lists before storing them, given that he intends to matrix-multiply them later. I think `m_objects.append(a)` etc would work just as well.

Comment: @SubhaneilLahiri Yes, actually I had a problem with the end result being a list. I managed to circumvent that with code I had already written. Your tip was very useful too. Thank you to both of you.